# BETWEEN statement inclusivity with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Beginner question:

I am trying to understand why a timestamp bracket is not behaving as I expect.
I have a table with data every minute; For this example, I have records at 14:55:00 and 14:56:00.

```
WHERE ts BETWEEN '2021-08-01 14:55:00Z' AND '2021-08-01 14:55:00Z'  (14:55 to 14:55)
```

doesn't return me anything, while the doc says between is inclusive, but

```
WHERE ts BETWEEN '2021-08-01 14:55:00Z' AND '2021-08-01 14:56:00Z'  (14:55 to 14:56)
```

returns me a singe result (14:55, not including 14:56), and

```
WHERE ts >= '2021-08-01 14:55:00Z' AND ts <='2021-08-01 14:55:00Z'
```

also doesn't return me any result while I do have a record at 14:55 and both conditions should be true.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Screenshot requested by Caius:

```
SELECT to_char(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.USTZ') 
FROM t 
WHERE ts BETWEEN '2021-08-01 14:55:00Z' AND '2021-08-01 14:56:00Z'
```

[image]

Comment: Milliseconds on your in-table time? `2021-08-01 14:55:00.123Z` is not between ..55 and ..55 but is between ..55 and ..56. nb; BETWEEN is inclusive at both ends

Comment: yes, I have ms but everything is rounded by the minute, so the ms fields are always at 0. Do I need to precise the ms in the queries? (isn't the date matching done through ms internally? numbers should line up)

Comment: The result you show `14:55` does not include seconds much less the fractional seconds @CaiusJard mentions, yet you are comparing to the second level: `2021-08-01 14:55:00Z`. You need to decide what level of detail in the timestamp you want to declare to and then normalize your query to that level.

Comment: Just don't use `BETWEEN` for such queries but a right open interval where the right boundary is one *more*  in the unit you want to "round" to: `ts >= '2021-08-01 14:55:00Z'::timestamptz AND ts < '2021-08-01 14:55:00Z'::timestamptz + '1 second'::interval` That covers the case when the precision is finer than anticipated or changes to a finer setting. (And BTW, `BETWEEN` isn't a statement but an operator/operation.)

Comment: Tell you what, run `SELECT to_char(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.USTZ') FROM t WHERE ts BETWEEN '2021-08-01 14:55:00Z' AND '2021-08-01 14:56:00Z'`, post a screenshot of the result and we'll maybe able to tell you why

Comment: @stickybit, that is misleading. If you really want the upper limit to be HH:MM:00 then make it so. Then if you don't get the results you want you know the data is not conforming to your expectations, instead of hiding the overruns. Basically the equivalent of hiding a bad engine sound by turning up the radio.

Comment: @CaiusJard, I added the screenshot. My queries return a time in the format 00:00:00.000000 (microseconds).

Comment: So you are not rounding to whole minutes, you have fractional seconds. If you want to deal with the current data and round to minutes then do something like: `select '2021-08-01 14:55:00.087'::timestamp(0); 2021-08-01 14:55:00`.

Comment: ok, I get it now; I have to review the rounding then! I'll have a look at report here

Comment: See my update to previous comment.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: In the rare case that you want to check if the data is "rounded" it's misleading, yes. But in the majority of cases people that's not what people want to do. I may or may not misunderstand the OP here.

Comment: The OP was quite explicit about expecting inclusive behavior from the end points in the statement.  The question was why that was not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per initial suspicions, your times have a millisecond component so they are not "between" the specified times; 14:55:00.087 is no more "between 14:55 and 14:55" than 1.0123 is "between 1.01 and 1.01"

They show up when you widen the range to a minute; they would even show up if you widened it to a second etc

ps; Postgres wouldn't receive a request for "x between 1.01 and 1.01" and automagically truncate all the decimal values in x such that stored data of 1.0123 became 1.01 and realized a "true" WHERE; the data stays as is, and the result of the `BETWEEN`  Is false - if you want to truncate table data to eg 2 decimal places you have to specify that by writing out the relevant process in the WHERE, but you would be advised not to manipulate table data in a WHERE clause (it typically kills performance/means indexes cannot be used etc)

I've talked a lot about decimal numbers here, purely because it's easier to conceive the point in putting across with decimals than time stamps, but all in, they work in the same way

Comment: ok, I get it; so the query doesn't handle any rounding based on the precision passed, I have to do that in the data itself

Comment: It would be best, I think. If you'll one day need the extra precision, store it somewhere but for querying purposes against this data, either make sure it's stored as `14:55:00.000000` and then you can use "whole" numbers in BETWEEN. The recommendations to use a pair of `>=` and `<` are often more useful, especially if you want to keep those milliseconds for some other use, though it might make querying slower - you can get quite different indexing and query engine behaviors out of 10 records all 14:55:00.000 versus 10 records of varying milliseconds at the end- see "index cardinality"